# Datepicker default year error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My datepicker has an error, that if you didnt choose or select a year, for example a user selects `May 25, 1935`  (well 1935 is the lowest and default year). In the textbox it will show as `2015/05/25` or May 25, 2015.

Here's the code so you can see the error.

```js
$(function() {
  var startDate = "1935";
  var endDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;
  var interval = startDate + ":" + endDate;
  $("#from2").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: interval,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });

  $("#to2").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: '1935:' + (new Date).getFullYear(),
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#from2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <label for="from">Birthday</label>
  <input type="text" id="from2" name="from">



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is setting the [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) to `"+1w"` which means **"add one week to today"**. You should probably do something like:

```
defaultDate: "1/1/1935"
```

Or you can just set your default date after instantiating the datepicker, by using the proper setter method:

```
$('#my-datepicker').datepicket(/* instantiation options */)
                   .datepicker( "setDate", YOUR_DEFAULT_DATE );  // use setter
```

Here's an example of both:

```js
$(function() {
  var startDate = "1935";
  var endDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;
  var interval = startDate + ":" + endDate;
  
  // use default date
  $("#one").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "1/1/1935",  // set default date
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: interval
  });
  
  // use setter
  $("#two").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: interval
  }).datepicker("setDate", "1/1/1935"); // set default date

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <label for="one">Birthday</label>
  <input type="text" id="one" name="one">

  <label for="two">Birthday 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="two" name="two">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible, that there is no display default?

Comment: @Vista no problem, glad to help